# Ruby on Rails. Load dynamic partial layouts with share data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm novice to Ruby and Ruby on Rails
I'm trying to load templates dynamically with shared data
I have a quizz (named game in my code) and I will add some questions to the game and some answers to these questions dynamically.

In my games/index.html.erb I have

```
<div class="form-group game">
  <%= form.label(':name', "Quizz title") %>
  <%= form.text_field ':name', class: 'form-control form-control-sm' %>
</div>

<div class="questions"></div>

<div class="row form-actions">
  <div class="col-sm">  
    <%= link_to 'Add a question', add_partial_question_games_path, remote: true, "data-turbolinks": false, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm text-right">
    <%= form.submit 'Save', :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on 'add a question' link I append the partial layout of question which contains a link to append the answer partial layout. So I have datas on this order:

QUIZZ

- Question 1

  - Answer 1.1
  - Answer 1.2
  - Add answer link
- Question 2

  - Answer 2.1
  - Answer 2.2
  - Answer 2.3
  - Answer 2.4
  - Add an answer link

Add a question link

SAVE THE QUIZZ

my controller remote actions are:

```
  def add_partial_question
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def add_partial_answer
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

and the corresponding *.js.erb files are:

```
// add_partial_question.js.erb
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.questions').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'games/partials/question') %>");
});

// add_partial_answer.js.erb
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.answers').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'games/partials/answer', :locals => { :question_key => question_key }) %>");
});
```

my 'partials/_question.html.erb' contains

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <%= link_to 'Add an answer', add_partial_answer_games_path, remote: true, "data-turbolinks": false, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the partials/_answer.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <%= text_field_tag "game[questions][#{question_key}][answers][#{answer_key}][text]", 'Your answer', class: "form-control"  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't any idea how I shall init, passe and increment the question_key and answer_key from controller remote actions to these partial views. Which is the best way ? 
When I try to pass any variables from remote actions to the *.js.erb and then to pass them to the views it doesn't work.
I've tried to do something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :locals => { :question_key => params[:question_key].to_i + 1 } }
end
```

it doesn't work.

Any ideas ?
Thank you very mutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little bit of mess in your question, for example in your `// add_partial_answer.js.erb` you used variable question_key which isn't define, your controller isn't RESTful etc. So instead of checking your code step by step I am dropping [here link for a great railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?autoplay=true) where you will find answer. I am hoping it will help with your problem.

Comment: Hi, yeah my code was not complete. Thank a lot for your great link, I've found my answer here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast